# How do I make the results for a invalid option show

Tags: vb.net, console-application

need help to make the input of 101 show as invalid  instead of A* as an output on a console app from visual studio code

```
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim mark As Byte
        Dim grade As String

        Console.WriteLine("enter a mark out of 100")
        mark = Console.ReadLine
        If mark <= 39 Then
            grade = "u"

        ElseIf mark <= 49 Then
            grade = ("e")

        ElseIf mark <= 59 Then
            grade = ("d")

        ElseIf mark <= 69 Then
            grade = ("C")

        ElseIf mark <= 79 Then
            grade = ("B")

        ElseIf mark <= 89 Then
            grade = ("A")

        ElseIf mark >= 99 Then
            grade = ("A*")

        Else
            grade = ("invailid")

        End If

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Grade is :" & grade)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Easy solution: `Instead of ElseIf mark >= 99 Then` use `ElseIf mark <=100 Then` , you  checked already for the other conditions above of it. I said easy because I think an array logic would be better to avoid having too many if lines, but that would be a slighlty more abstract approach, which can be hard to grasp if you're getting into porgramming: I think it's good to do it as you did to understand the fundamentals.

Comment: **First** check for valid input. If the input is not valid, **do not** try to process it. Too many problems have happened (and are still happening) because of a failure to do that simple input validation.

Comment: @Sgdva Please notice that the code as presented is trying to compare a string to numbers.

Comment: You also aren't allowing for a number less than zero or a non-number. Maybe you're allowed to make that assumption for this homework assignment but, if not, you should be making those checks.

Comment: Are you required to use `If` statements for this homework because this situation would be better served by a `Select Case`.